# How to create a json file and then return it in a get request back to react app

Tags: java, json, reactjs, spring-boot, fetch

I am trying to create a JSON File *sample.json* and I am trying to create this file in my spring boot backend controller and be able to send it to my react app where it will trigger the download of the file to the client

I want to make sure That I am actually returning the actual file from the response that is given from the http get request, and I would like to know how to trigger download of that actual response 
React

```
fetch('/api/download')
  .then((res) => {
     return res.blob();
  }).then((body) => {
      console.log(body);
      setTimeout(() => {
         URL.createObjectURL(body)
      }, 300);
  }).catch((error) => {
     console.log(error);
  })
```

My end goal is to be able to have the generated file in the backend come through the get request and be able to trigger the download please let me know how this is possible. thank you.

Comment: Why does your `fetch` have a `then` that doesn't return anything as second handler? `fetch` gets the URL content, the first `then` gets the resulting network object, exacts the body, and forwards that. The second `then` gets that body, and does, effetively, nothing. Yes, it "does" something, but the result gets thrown away because (a) you don't return anything and (b) the "doing" happens in a timeout so will run in a completely different scope, and completely independent of the promise chain. Why is your second `then` not `.then( body => URL.createObjectURL(body))` ?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans okay with discarding the second then function is my spring code returning an actual file and how am I able to trigger a download with the body that I am returning ?

Comment: before we answer that, can you narrow down your question to _either_ asking about the server side, or the client side code? Either your endpoint works (it sends you the data you need) and is not related to the actual problem, or your client code works (which I'm assuming is the part you're having problems with) and _it_ shouldn't be in the post. Try to keep your question [as focused on only the problem at hand](/help/how-to-ask) as possible.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have edited the question to show you what my client code is and how I am trying to retrieve the blob which is my JSON file that I have made and I would like to trigger the download of that file.

Comment: Thank you. On a side note, why the `setTimeout`? You're already working asynchronously, so what benefit do you think adding that has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to not use `fetch` but use a normal link element:

```html
<a href="/api/download" download="sample.json">Click to download</a>
```

In all modern browsers, that `download` attribute will cause the browser to save the link response as a file. No `fetch` required.

However, if you absolutely need a `fetch` operation, then you can basically do this in JS itself: fetch your result, then create an `<a>`, set its `href` attribute to a file blob, and make sure the `download` attribute is set:

```js
fetch(...)
.then(res => res.blob())
.then(blob => {
  const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  // create our <a> to force a download for the response
  const dl = document.createElement(`a`);
  dl.href = blobURL;
  dl.download = `sample.json`;

  // In order for the link to "trigger" we need to add it to the document.
  // If we don't, dl.click() won't do anything. So add it, click it, then remove it.
  dl.style.display = `none`;
  document.body.appendChild(dl);
  dl.click();
  document.body.removeChild(dl);
});
```

Comment: So you basically just displayed the a tag and as soon as the clock which initiated the download and got rid of the tag right after

Comment: it's never displayed, because it has display:none. It just needs to be in the DOM for the click to actually work, and once it's been clicked, it's no longer needed.